# Flask WSGI logging logs at the wrong level on Apache2

Tags: python, apache, logging, flask, wsgi

This is an example of my apache error.log:

```
[Fri Oct 16 18:28:24.816206 2015] [:info] [pid 13739:tid 139772762691456] mod_wsgi (pid=13739): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Oct 16 18:28:41.608894 2015] [:info] [pid 13739:tid 139772651718400] [remote 10.1.10.37:56161] mod_wsgi (pid=13739, process='dsapp', application=''): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/blackbird/blackbird.wsgi'.
[Fri Oct 16 18:28:42.176915 2015] [:info] [pid 13740:tid 139772651718400] [remote 10.1.10.154:49761] mod_wsgi (pid=13740, process='app2', application=''): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/whiteboard_v2/whiteboard.wsgi'.
[Fri Oct 16 18:28:45.863991 2015] [:error] [pid 13740:tid 139772467078912] INFO:app.api.routes:API/search: ImmutableMultiDict([('m', 'n'), ('q', '')])
```

Notice the very last log entry [:error].

I would like to log at the appropriate level on apache2. I would like the last entry to say [:info] rather than [:error].

My Flask-WSGI is configured as follows:

```
from flask import redirect, url_for, jsonify, request, send_file, current_app
from . import api
from flask.ext.cors import cross_origin
from ..models import Inventory
from app import db
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@api.route('/api/search', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def index():
    d=request.args['q']
    m=request.args['m']
    logger.info('API/search: %s', request.args)
```

You can clearly see my intent is 'info'. How can I configure Apache to log at the approrpiate level so my flask logger.info reads [:info] rather than [:error]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python logging levels are not related to Apache logging levels.  Apparently, Apache treats output from the app mod_wsgi is running as `error` level.  Let your web server log web server related things.  Configure Python to send your app logs to some other file.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='/path/to/app.log', level=logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 2):

Error log level is used at Apache level when stdout/stderr is used to ensure that any messages would generally be output. If this wasn't done and you tried to use Python level log level to try and turn debug on, you would never see it in Apache logs if it was passed through to Apache at debug level. This is because Apache log level would override and suppress it. You wouldn't want to be setting Apache log level to allow it as it would generate huge amounts of noise from Apache modules you really wouldn't want.

So just ignore the fact that Apache says it is an error level and be happy that it still actually being logged. It really is the best compromise in the face of having two log level settings, one in Apache and one in Python.

Overall I would recommend against configuring Python logging to use a distinct file as suggested by others unless you ensure you are using a logging handler that correctly handles writing from multiple processes and log rotation properly. Apache handles both of those fine, but Python standard loggers don't.